# When to use which Feature Importance Method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am trying to find features of importance. I am using different models but each of them give me different results and I cannot wrap my head around why. I looked to see which assumptions work for each model but I am not able to find anything here either.

I am using XGBoost, Logistic Regression, RFE, Permutation Importance, and Decision Tree. How can I test which one is the best? Is there any quality metrics I can use? Also, for some models the output does not map to the actual feature name rather to numbers like feature 0, feature 1, etc. How can I map those to my actual features?

```
#XG BOOST 

# split data into train and test sets
test_size = 0.3
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=test_size)

#instantiate model and train
model = XGBClassifier(learning_rate = 0.05, n_estimators=200, max_depth=4)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# make predictions for test set
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))

# plot feature importance
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
plot_importance(model,ax=ax)


#PERMUTATION IMPORTANCE
train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=1)
my_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,
                                  random_state=0).fit(train_X, train_y)


perm = PermutationImportance(my_model, random_state=1).fit(val_X, val_y)
eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names = val_X.columns.tolist())

# RECURSIVE FEATURE ELIMINATION
X = x
Y = y
# feature extraction
model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
rfe = RFE(model, 3)
fit = rfe.fit(X, Y)
print("Num Features: %d" % fit.n_features_)
print("Selected Features: %s" % fit.support_)
print("Feature Ranking: %s" % fit.ranking_)

# LOG REGRESSION
model = LogisticRegression()
# fit the model
model.fit(x, y)
# get importance
importance = model.coef_[0]
# summarize feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
# plot feature importance
pyplot.bar([x for x in range(len(importance))], importance)
pyplot.show()

# DECISION TREE
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
# fit the model
model.fit(x, y)
# get importance
importance = model.feature_importances_
# summarize feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
# plot feature importance
pyplot.bar([x for x in range(len(importance))], importance)
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all - it is important to tune hyperparameters of the models, default values could work in many cases.

Second: feature importance shows the importance of features for the model, it doesn't show the quality of the models.

> Also, for some models the output does not map to the actual feature name rather to numbers like feature 0, feature 1, etc.

The numbers refer to the list of features in your data. So if your data, for example, has columns ['age', 'area', 'weather'], then 0 - age, 1 - area, 2 - weather.

As for comparing the models - you should use metrics: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

For the classification the most commonly used metrics are f1-score and accuracy.